# This MSE question was rejected for a migration on MO. Are you agree with this decision?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, math-stackexchange

One month ago, I've asked the following question on MSE:

[Is the left regular representation of an algebra, always faithful?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1012748/84284)

Up to now, this question has received 5 upvotes but no answer.
I've flagged the question for a migration on MO, but it was rejected (see below).

Are you agree with this decision?
(if possible, could you explain your opinion?)

> I would like to migrate this post on mathoverflow. – Sébastien Palcoux Nov 19 at 13:22
>   declined - They rejected your question.
>    Why did they reject this question? – Sébastien Palcoux Nov 20 at 11:56
>   declined - For further on what is and isn't desired at MO, I recommend asking at MO.

Comment: If migration gets rejected, you could also try describing the problem and giving a link in this MO meta thread: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1967/55893

Comment: It seems to me that "they" here is the moderators, and the "rejected" refers to the reply to an informal request and not an actual migration that was rejected. Thus, it might be better to contact the moderators directly, as only they can answer your question. The question that could be addressed here is whether or not the community at large agrees with this decision. If you want to discuss this, you should make it clear.

Comment: @quid: Thank you! I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @quid: I think that in this case it's preferable to ask on meta.MO because it might be the case that some users may think this question is a good fit, and perhaps these users are sufficiently knowledgeable in the relevant fields so that their opinion can be taken seriously by the moderators, and the question can/will be migrated. It might also be good that to know, at least once (or twice?) why do the moderators think a question shouldn't be migrated. At least for future reference.

Comment: @Asaf I am not sure you saw the original version of the question that asked only *why* it was rejected (the answer to which is obvious from the transcribed conversation on the flags). I agree the current version is alright as a question. To insist on this change might be a bit nit-picking, but an implicit goal was also to make clear what "rejection" means in this case, which I thought was relevant as "rejected migration" has as you know a specific technical meaning other than the current usage.

Comment: @quid: Admittedly, I didn't check the previous versions. I agree with your assessment, too.

Answer (score 9):

My memory of what happened is this: I was pinged to come over to the moderator chat room and was asked if we "wanted" three MSE posts to be migrated. I said I wasn't sure about the post in question, meaning I wasn't sure whether actual experts would keep it open if it were migrated -- the MSE moderator took that as a "no". I told the other MO moderators what had transpired, with no complaints and one thumbs up.

As quid says, it was a very informal request, and I gave only my off-the-cuff impressions, merely saying I wasn't sure about this case. I for one have no particular issue with the question (I *certainly* wouldn't vote to close myself) and don't want to be a roadblock for the OP. I would be fine if he simply "crossposted" to MO (linking to this discussion) and took his chances as it were. Or, we could open the discussion here and ask if it seems suitable for MO, preferably hearing from people more expert than me.