# Advice to young mathematicians question on Mathematics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, math-stackexchange

(I don't know if this is on-topic on MathOverflow-meta. In case it is not, please, let me know.)

I see that many active users of MathOverflow are not as active on Math Stack Exchange; for this reason, I would like to draw their attention on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041623/advice-to-young-mathematicians-see-rota-tao-and-the-princeton-companion-to-ma) that I recently asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange, in the hope that some of them will spare some time to share their insights on the topic.

Kindest regards.

Comment: You might have posted this in http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se

Comment: @quid Thank you very much for pointing out that thread (of which I was not aware). However, as the questions already has a fantastic answer by Georges Elencwajg, it doesn't feel right to me to say that it was not "sufficiently answered". Still, I would really appreciate to see the point of view of different people on this topic because, as prof. T. Gowers noted in *The Princeton Companion to Mathematics* (p. 1000), "what was more surprising was that there was remarkably little overlap between the contributions".

Comment: I went to "***this question***" right away, on Dec 14, left 4 answers, got two irrelevant  (hence offensive) comments, and have removed my answers--a logical reaction.

Comment: It is soo... general! Yes, most of us have a lot to say on the subject (though one friend of mine firmly believes that everybody sees things and thinks about them in their own way and all we can share and teach is a formal record of our achievements and, in exceptional cases, failures; the point of view we argue endlessly about). However, good books on this have already been written and unless you tell clearly what is missing there for you or what points seem to require further discussion, you'll just be learning the value of ${100 \choose 10}$. Interesting, perhaps, but such a waste of time!