# I want to post a question on MathOverflow, but is it suitable?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question, math-stackexchange, cross-posting

I posted a question ["A question on the remainders of integer division"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264083/a-question-on-the-remainders-of-integer-division) on Mathematics one week ago. There is not any answer until now.

I do not think it is a question of professional level, but it seems impossible to find an answer there. So is it suitable if I post it on MathOverflow for looking for some (any) idea or hint?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: [This meta thread](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se) might be an intermediate solution, before moving the question to MO.

Comment: Thank you for your generous help!

Comment: You could also try answering a few questions on math.se to build up enough rep to offer a bounty.

Comment: According to the description of MO, if a question is not on professional level then it is not suited for MO.