# Migrating question from Math SE

Tags: discussion, specific-question, math-stackexchange

I posted this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379205/weil-pairing-on-linear-algebraic-groups/) on Math SE a month ago but it has had no responses even though I also placed a bounty on it.

Whilst it is at graduate level, I'm unsure whether to ask it here since the question may seem too broad and any answer I get on MO may be too high above my level understanding (I only recently started to learn about algebraic groups).

However, I am still keen on getting some sort of answer to my question, so I would be grateful if you could tell me how to adjust it to make it less broad (eg whether I need to place further hypotheses like reductive etc) and suitable to MO without overcomplicating it.

Comment: You can also try [this](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se).