# Shall I ask my questions about Algebraic geometry on MO instead of MSE?

Tags: discussion

I searched for similar questions on MSE, like [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22036/too-difficult-for-mse-and-too-easy-for-mo-questions) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo), but couldn't figure out my solution. And since I intended to ask whether I can post my questions on MO, so I think I should ask here.

I know MO is about research-related questions, so I always feel reluctant to ask my questions here. However, I've asked several questions about algebraic geometry on MSE but got no answers, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601306/dimension-of-variety-vi-where-i-langle-xy-xz-rangle-in-kx-y-z-k-is), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603634/show-that-the-singular-locus-sigma-of-an-affine-variety-v-contains-no-irred) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376662/translate-a-geometric-theorem-into-polynomial-equations-theorem-of-the-orthoc). Since I am self-learning this topic, I really hope I can get help. So can I ask these questions on MO? Or future questions like these on MO?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have plenty of rep on MSE - why not offer some bounties to attract attention to your questions?

Comment: @Carl: Nice suggestion! I forgot to think about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These types of questions look like homework to me and are not really appropriate for MO. That said, there are some homework-like problems that are of genuine research interest so the rule isn't completely black and white. But your questions appear to be fairly standard homework problems designed to test and expand basic understanding of the material. I imagine if you are patient you will get some answers on MSE. It might help to try to raise awareness of your questions, much like you are doing now. There is a thread on this forum for precisely this purpose.

[Interesting (and not sufficiently answered) questions on math.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the reference. I am not even sure whether my questions are interesting enough to get attention at the linked thread though, considering the few questions asked there and the few visitors. Also it seems to me it is not intended for homework questions either. I guess I just have to be patient or try to figure them out by myself.

Comment: Patience is one of the best learning tools.  I wish I had more of it!

Comment: @Ryan: Patience. You'll get there! Just be patient, and you'll eventually find yourself having more patience.