# How can I tell if my question is appropriate to MathOverflow or if I should just put a bounty on it at Math.SE?

Tags: discussion

I have at least two questions which are about graduate level mathematics on Math.SE, but about which I have serious doubts regarding whether or not they are "research level". In other words, I don't think they are open problems, but then again I don't know enough to confirm that suspicion either. I also suspect the reason why they are unanswered on Math.SE is that they are just uninteresting, but at least one of the questions has enough upvotes that that seems somewhat unlikely.

Also for the record, I am going to wait at least one week (both questions are still only a couple of days old) before actually considering re/cross-posting them anywhere.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830287/corollaries-of-the-yoneda-lemma-in-analysis#comment3750496_1830287

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827803/can-local-martingales-be-characterized-only-using-their-fv-process-and-bm#comment3750361_1827803

I have a lot of reluctance to post on Mathoverflow, even if my questions are appropriate, because the only research I have done was in applied mathematics which used a lot of numerical simulations to form conjectures, and though I have at least the prerequisites to study graduate level algebra/topology, the only graduate level mathematics I have seriously studied is in analysis and probability theory (although I do want to rectify that somewhat now that I am done with undergrad); also I am pursuing a PhD in statistics, not pure mathematics, and as one commenter on Math.SE put it "statistics is a well-known easier subsubject of mathematics, so any question you could possibly have about statistics could be answered on Math.SE".

I know there are people who do statistical research without mathematical rigor, but personally I am of the opinion that if one is not utilizing the full amount of mathematical knowledge which applicable to statistics (which even exceeds the reified realms of analysis and probability theory) is not doing such research correctly. Admittedly this might be a minority opinion.

Anyway, if anyone thinks the two questions I linked to above are stupid, please let me know, so I don't waste anyone's time in a week or so trying to cross-post them here if they don't receive any answers on Math.SE.

Comment: The first question is not at all a stupid question (I don't have an opinion on the second, as it is not an area of current interest to me), but I don't think it's going to be good for MO. I think for me the challenge in answering the first at Math.SE is how to pitch an answer that would fit in meaningfully with (my rough estimate of) your background and also with the intuition you are trying to convey. There are probably lots of different types of responses which would go off in various directions, but I imagine not all of them would pack the same punch for you.

Comment: BTW there exist the tags ([meta-tag:math-stackexchange]) and ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) on this meta; if you consider some of those two tags relevant for you question, you should add it. I am not sure whether you did this on purpose, but in both cases you have linked to comments instead of to the questions.

Comment: +1 for waiting a week.  Some people panic if their question is not answered in 1 hour...

Comment: To me (a non-expert in either question) it seems you are doing exactly the right thing - looking for answers to mathematics questions with a high chance that somebody in this community can answer (there is no requirement that a question be open, in fact this probably means it's too hard) and would be of interest to researchers expert in some but not other fields of mathematics.  You are waiting before cross-posting and will cross-link.  So, go ahead.  What is the worst that can happen?

Comment: Don't forget http://stats.stackexchange.com, if you have statistics questions...

Answer (score 3):

I can offer some general advice about cross posting. I would have preferred to comment rather than answer, but I currently don't have enough reputation here to do so. Anyway, I have had the same problem. Initially I was cautious and asked the question on Math.SE, as you have done, however someone there commented that if I rewrote the question it might be better off on mathoverflow. My advice would be therefore that if no-one on Math.SE suggests this, perhaps tactfully suggest it yourself in a comment. Even if someone can't answer the question for you, they may have the necessary expertise to judge whether or not the question warrants cross posting and therefore be in a position to advise you.

Answer (score 3):

Also, forgive me if you've already seen this but I don't think anyone has pointed the following post (or maybe thread) out:

[Interesting (and not sufficiently answered) questions on math.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se)

You might want to try adding an answer there. Looking at the (currently) last answer, it seems to be acceptable for non-experts to do so.

Comment: You can edit your answers by clicking the "edit" button directly under them, rather than answering twice, where one is an addendum to the other (or at least, seems to be at a glance)