# Appropriateness and cross-posting

Tags: discussion, on-topic, cross-posting

I am interested in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3958398/573047) on math.stackexchange. To me it is interesting because while it looks "obvious" that there isn't a solution with 6 turns (I have some very partial results about this), it seems very hard to prove, or at least nobody was able to solve it so far.

Question 1: is the above question appropriate for mathoverflow? Since the problem looks so hard, maybe somebody here knows some powerful technique or have enough experience to say that this will probably remain an open problem.

Question 2: if yes for Q1, how long should I wait before cross-posting here? (Obviously making a note on the other site about the cross-post)

Comment: I have added the tags ([meta-tag:on-topic]) and ([meta-tag:cross-posting]). Perhaps ([meta-tag:specific-question]) could be suitable, too.

Comment: Some links related to cross-posting can be found [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/cross-posting/info). And there is also this thread: [Interesting (and not sufficiently answered) questions on math.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1967).